# I need help setting the RecordSource of a Report within a VBA Function

Tags: ms-access, vba

Ok, so I've been looking around here for a few days (and a few other sites) and while I have modified my code a good bit to find a solution, it still doesn't work.

I have four `source` queries, and I'd like to set the record source of my report to one of four queries based on options selected in a different form. Anyway the function looks like this:

```
Function PrintMod()

    DoCmd.OpenReport "PrntRep", acViewPreview

    Dim Source As String
    If Forms![Search Form]!Subform1.SourceObject = "Query.SearchQuery" Then
        Source = "SELECT * FROM SearchQuery"
    ElseIf Forms![Search Form]!Subform1.SourceObject = "Query.Part Number Query" Then
        Source = "SELECT * FROM [Part Number Query]"
    ElseIf Forms![Search Form]!Subform1.SourceObject = "Query.Keyword Query" Then
        Source = "SELECT * FROM [Keyword Query]"
    ElseIf Forms![Search Form]!Subform1.SourceObject = "Query.ROP Query" Then
        Source = "SELECT * FROM [ROP Query]"
    Else
        Source = "SELECT * FROM Inventory"
    End If

    CurrentDb.QueryDefs("ReportSource").SQL = Source


End Function
```

What it's supposed to do is open the `PrntRep` report, set the `Source` variable and then set the report's record source.

Comment: Your description sounds like you want to alter the report's Record Source property, but that code changes the SQL property of a saved query named *ReportSource*.  What do you have as the report's Record Source?  And what happens as a result of that code when it doesn't work?  Is there an error?  If not, please explain the differences between what it does and what you want it to do.

Comment: I realized that about a minute after I posted this, but was offline for a bit. I since set the recordsource to the ReportSource query like I had meant to, and applied the fix suggested below, and I've got it working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to shuffle the order:

```
Function PrintMod()

    Dim Source As String

    Select Case Forms![Search Form]!Subform1.SourceObject
        Case "Query.SearchQuery" 
            Source = "SELECT * FROM SearchQuery"
        Case "Query.Part Number Query" 
            Source = "SELECT * FROM [Part Number Query]"
        Case "Query.Keyword Query" 
            Source = "SELECT * FROM [Keyword Query]"
        Case "Query.ROP Query" 
            Source = "SELECT * FROM [ROP Query]"
        Case Else
            Source = "SELECT * FROM Inventory"
    End Select 

    CurrentDb.QueryDefs("ReportSource").SQL = Source

    DoCmd.OpenReport "PrntRep", acViewPreview

End Function
```

Comment: With that and a realization that I had made a stupid mistake, I fixed the problem. I also hadn't set the RecordSource of the report. Thanks.